# Center of semi-direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, p-groups

Let $G = A \rtimes B$ be a finite group ($A$ is the normal subgroup), where $A$ is a non-abelian $p$-group and $(|B|,p) = 1.$

Then what can we say about the center of $G?$ Does it always lie inside $A?$

What should be the condition on $B$ so that $Z(G) \subseteq A?$ Can we conclude anything if $|B| < |A|$

The only fact that I know is that in some cases if $A$ is abelian (but $G$ is non-abelian), then $C_A(B) = Z(G).$ But I have no idea what happens if $A$ is non-abelian.

Comment: Your fact is not correct. For example, $C_3\rtimes C_2$ with trivial action has centre of order $6$. Even $C_3\rtimes C_4$ with non-trivial action has centre of order $2$.

Comment: @ David A. Craven Thanks for your response. Suppose we are not considering trivial actions. Then when is that fact true?

Comment: It's true if the action of $B$ on $A$ is faithful, i.e., $B$ is just a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$. But then this statement has nothing to do with $A$ being abelian.

Comment: Ok. Suppose I have $G = A \rtimes B,$ where $|A| = p^n$ and $|B| = (p-1)^m, p \geq 5.$ Then is there some approach to see whether action of $B$ on $A$ is faithful or not?

Comment: I'm not sure the question makes sense. A given action is either faithful (i.e., the map $B\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is injective) or not. It has less to do with the orders of $A$ and $B$ and more to do with the structure of $A$, hence of its automorphism group. You cannot ask the question unless you have a map $B\to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$.

Comment: A necessary condition for $Z(G)\subseteq A$ is that $Z(B)\cap\ker(\phi)$ be trivial, where $\phi\colon B\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is the morphism that determines the semidirect product.